# Node.js or Java for a online cab project

Tags: java, node.js

I got a new online cab booking project which involves a lot of transactions and algorithms for which i need to choose a technology i have confuse between node.js & mongo db or java & mongodb, experts please advice me which one to choose for this project?

Comment: This question is way too broad and has no specific right answer. It is more of a discussion topic than something that fits in the StackOverflow Q&A format.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want a setup that "Avoids the headache of configuration" I will suggest you to use a NodeJS & MongoDB there is already a framework available to meet all your needs :The MEAN Stack of Node JS (mean.io) which can be used to full stack development.